# Complete Internet Explorer Authentication Dialog with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I am using Selenium to simulate a user to automate some legacy software. The software works only with IE6 (I'm using IE11 in compatibility mode) and is a bit crap.

There is a point in the software where the Windows Security dialog appears. This requires credentials before the user/simulator can proceed.

I'm using `IAlert.SetAuthenticationCredentials` to try and populate the dialog but this doesn't seem to work. To move on from this, I can enter the details manually, but then Selenium seems to thing the main browser window has been closed:

> Currently focused window has been closed.

The `WindowHandles` collection at this point is empty, but the browser window is still open, and has rendered the correct page.

What's going on here?

[image: Screenshot]

**UPDATE**

The answers provided are suggestions on how to handle the dialog. I'm wondering why Selenium thinks the browser window is closed when in fact it is still there.

Comment: Can you blindly use something like SendKeys? I don't think you'll be able to target that security window, just like you can't target the UAC interface :/

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to interract with native windows via `selenium`. The way to deal with your issue is for example to use analogue of `Robot` in Java. Since you are using `C#` there is a simulator here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library.

Example code would be like following:

```
// Simulate (Ctrl + C) shortcut, which is copy for most applications
KeyboardSimulator.SimulateStandardShortcut(StandardShortcut.Copy);

// This does the same as above
KeyboardSimulator.KeyDown(Keys.Control);
KeyboardSimulator.KeyPress(Keys.C);
KeyboardSimulator.KeyUp(Keys.Control);
```

There are also Mouse simulators, so with this framework it will be possible to enter the required values in window and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch to that alert by,

```
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("Username", "Pwd");
alert.Accept();
```

I have tested it and it works for IE11, selenium v3.1.0

Ref: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IAlert_SetAuthenticationCredentials.htm

Suggesstion 1-Go to internet explorer settings->security settings-> user authentication-> select automatic login with current username and password.[image]

Suggesstion 2- if your application has access to it's API, then login via API, get the authentication token and set the auth.token in browser cookie.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Regarding solution 2, there is no API, hence the use of Selenium. There's also no login page, so requires the auth credentials. I understand there used to be able to do this in the url like `https://{username:password}:domain.com` but it's deprecated.

Comment: Regarding solution 1, the Windows user is not the user for this application.

Comment: Did you try this: https://Aladdin:OpenSesame@www.example.com/index.html  where Aladdin is username and OpenSesame is password?

Comment: @SergiyKonoplyaniy Yes, it's deprecated and does not work. That's what I meant in my previous comment, forgive the incorrect syntax.